# Expressing both concurrency and time in activity diagrams

Tags: time, concurrency, uml, diagram, activity-diagram

I am not sure how to express my scenario using activity diagrams:

[image: UML activity diagrams]

What I am trying to visualise is the fact that:

- A message is received
- Two independent and concurrent actions take place: logging of the message and processing the message
- Logging always takes less time than processing

The first activity in the diagram is correct in the sense that the actions are independent but it does not relay the fact that logging is guaranteed to take less time than processing.

The second activity in the diagram is not correct because, even if logging completes before processing, it looks as though processing depended on the logging's finishing first and that does not represent the reality.

Here is a non-computer related example:

- You are a novice in birdwatching, trying to make your first notes in your notebook about birds passing by
- A flock of birds approaches, you try to recognise as many details as possible
- You want to write down the details in your notebook, but wait, you begin to realise that your theoretical background does not work in practice, what should be a quick scribble actually amounts to nothing in the end because you did not recognise anything
- In the meantime, the birds majestically flew away without waiting for you, the activity is gone
- Or maybe you did actually write it down, it took you only a moment and the birds are still nearby, slowly flying away, ending the activity again after some time
- Or maybe you were under such awe that you just kept watching at them, without taking any notes - they fly away, disappearing in the horizon, ending the activity
- After a few hours, you have enough notes and you come home very happy - maybe you did not capture everything but this was enough to make you smile anyway

I can always add a comment to a diagram to express it all somehow but I wonder, is there a more structured way to express what I described in an activity diagram? If not an activity diagram then what kind of a diagram would be better suited in your opinion? Thank you.

Comment: `Logging always takes less time than processing` in what this important to indicate ? How are you sure this is always the case, what real time operating system are you using ? They are timing diagram in UML, but probably you just know one is (very probably) done before the other without knowing the time each uses, you you can't use these diagrams

Comment: Thanks Bruno, I would like to try to express it in an activity diagram first, if it is possible, although I understand that timing diagrams exist too. This is not a real-time operating system but logging time is around 1ms whereas processing is counted in hours. Everything is possible given that it is not an RTOS so these are not hard guarantees. But I am asking to educate myself too and learn more about UML - I tend to read a lot of diagrams but have only recently started to produce them so I am just not sure here. For the sake of an example, we can assume this is an RTOS.

Comment: Or, we can also assume that this is not a computer system at all, that we model an activity where two persons agreed that the first one logs something to a book while the other one processes some information and it is guaranteed that the first one will finish earlier. In that case, I would not be sure how to express it as an activity diagram either.

Comment: if I am not wrong just put a note saying the log is short in time, if I well understand you do not need it is shorter. I also think the diagram will be more clear using a join ater the two actions, then from it a transition to the final node

Comment: Right, but if there is a join, it means that both actions need to complete before the whole activity is done, is that correct? If so, then this would not express the reality correctly because if logging fails for any reason, that does not stop processing from continuing and only when processing (alone, possibly) finishes, is the activity ended.

Comment: whatever the logging fails or not it finishes no ? Else that means it can not finish so it can be longer than the process, and if it does not finish your activity does not finish too. The fact the logging fails has no impact on the processing while the joinSpec of the join is a 'and'

Comment: OK, thanks, I understand your point.

Comment: Note if you are afraid the logging is still on going when the processing is done (so the reverse of the initial assumption you want to show) you can cancel the logging placing it in an interruptible activity region with an interrupting edge from a receive event, whose event is sent after the processing action.

Comment: Thanks for the tip - this is not my case but I am thankful nevertheless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first diagram assumes that the duration of logging is always shorter than processing:

- If this assumption is correct, the upper flow reaches the flow-final node, and the remaining flows continue until the first reaches the activity-final node.  Here, the processing continues and the activity ends when the processing ends. This is exactly what you want.
- But if once, the execution would deviate from this assumption and logging would get delayed for any reason, then the end of the processing would reach the activity-final node, resulting in the immediate interruption of all other ongoing activities.  So logging would not complete. Maybe it’s not a problem for you, but in most cases audit expects logs to be complete.

You may be interested in a safer way that would be to add a join node:

[image]

The advantage is that the activity does not depend on any assumptions. It will always work:

- whenever the logging is faster, the token on that flow will wait at the join node, and as soon as process is finished the activity (safely) the join can happen and the outgoing token reaches the end.  This is exactly what you currently expect.
- if the logging is exceptionally slower, no problem:  the processing will be over, but the activity will wait for the logging to be completed.

This robust notation makes logging like Schroedinger's cat in its box: we don't have to know what activity is longer or shorter.  At the end of the activity,  both actions are completed.

### Time in activity diagrams?

Activity diagrams are not really meant to express timing and duration. It's about the flow of control and the synchronization.

However, if time is important to you, you could:

- visually make one activity shorter than the other.  This is super-ambiguous and absolute meaningless from a formal UML point of view.  But it's intuitive when readers see the parallel flow (a kind of sublminal communication ;-) ) .
- add a comment note to express your assumption in plain English. This has the advantage of being very clear an unambiguous.
- using UML duration constraints.  This is often used in timing diagram, sometimes in sequence diagrams,  but in general not in activity diagrams (personally I have never seen it, but UML specs doesn't exclude it either).

Time is something very general in the UML specs, and defined independently of the diagram.  For example:

> 8.4.4.2: A Duration is a value of relative time given in an implementation specific textual format. Often a Duration is a non- negative integer expression representing the number of “time ticks” which may elapse during this duration.
>
> 8.5.1: An Interval is a range between two values, primarily for use in Constraints that assert that some other Element has a value in the given range. Intervals can be defined for any type of value, but they are especially useful for time and duration values as part of corresponding TimeConstraints and DurationConstraints.

In your case you have a duration observation for the processing (e.g. `d`),  and a duration constraint for the logging (e.g. `0..d`).

> 8.5.4.2: An IntervalConstraint is shown as an annotation of its constrainedElement. The general notation for Constraints may be used for an IntervalConstraint, with the specification Interval denoted textually (...).

Unfortunately little more is said. The only graphical examples are for messages in sequence diagrams (Fig 8.5 and 17.5) and for timing diagrams (Fig 17.28 to 17.30).  Nevertheless, the notation could be extrapolated for activity diagrams, but it would be so unusal that I'd rather recommend the comment note.

Comment: Thanks @Christophe but the first diagram is correct at its core. The processing activity should not wait for logging under any circumstances. Also, if logging fails or finishes before or after processing (however unlikely), it does not influence processing at all. Both logging and processing are completely independent and the only condition to end the activity is that the processing completes, not logging.

Comment: The only thing that I am not sure how to express is simply the fact that logging always completes sooner than processing. I understand what your diagram does but this is not what the modeled system is doing - in your diagram, both actions must complete before the activity ends and this is not how the system works.

Comment: @MarkWolfram I've added some more infos about notation.  I undersand your point.  Nevertheless, may I ask:  Would you really say that both activities are independent,  if the completion of the second would terminate the first?  And would your system really interupt the logging: what's the use of logs if one cannot be sure they are accurate?

Comment: I understand your questions and they are all valid, concrete ones but I asked this question to learn about expressing myself in UML on an abstract level without getting into implementation details which, as you can imagine, are far more complex than this diagram. I also added a non-programming example to the question to underscore that this is about modeling as such too. Thanks again for your updated answer, I will check the sections of the spec that you mentioned.

Comment: Hi @Christophe - it looks that no other answers are going to arrive. If you please remove the first part of yours, the one saying that my first diagram is invalid, I will be happy to accept the rest of your answer. Thanks.

Comment: @MarkWolfram I did not say it is invalid, I said it has a problem in some cases. But ok, since it’s not a problem for you, I reworded to make it neutral.

Comment: Thanks, not only is it not a problem - it is in fact the core idea of the diagram and that is what prompted me into asking about it all here, just like I described it in the initial message. I am going to accept your answer now, thanks.

Comment: Wait, hold on, I reread your answer once more - you are still discussing the idea of joining the actions. This is not how it works, please reread my question, having a join node is totally incorrect, there is no requirement that the activity end only if both actions complete.

Comment: @MarkWolfram I reread your answer:you claim that duration of logging is always shorter. if this is true the behavior described by your diagram and my alternative is the same. There is a difference only if your assumption is not verified. I could just ignore this in my answer. But I have a personal problem with logging being abruptly terminated. It’s probably because I was expert witness in Court, where logging is part of digital evidence and interrupted logging is seen as suspicious. This is probably why I feel I have to promote designs that guarantee logging reliability ;-)

Comment: Alright, I have no problems with your designing systems in one or another way. But here the system already exists, the logging always takes less time, it is not any "claim", it is a fact. I only wanted to discuss how to represent it in UML and you keep changing the system to match the diagram that you drew which represents another system that you designed earlier - this is good and I understand your point but this is not why I posted this question. Thanks again.

Comment: At any rate, you invested time in answering it all, even if that does not correspond fully to what I asked, so I am accepting the answer. Thanks.